# Could not load file or assembly 'RadMenu.Net2, Version=4.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bbe59a8ad3533e68'

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'RadMenu.Net2, Version=4.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bbe59a8ad3533e68' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'RadMenu.Net2, Version=4.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bbe59a8ad3533e68' could not be loaded.

Pls help me to resolved this error...

Answer (score 0):

This means that somewhere in your projects and/or web.config(s) you have a reference to this horribly old assembly (I think it is 8 or so years old). Remove it and migrate to the modern AJAX suite.